# Is it possible to Direct3D 9 debug DLL in an app using the release version

Tags: disassembly, windows

I have an application using d3d9.dll, but I want to figure out which functions it calls to gain insight.

Since online tools I have found are incompatible with my app (32-bit d3d9),
is it instead possible to use the d3d9d.dll (debug version), or somehow wrap the calls?

Comment: Hi and welcome to RE.SE. Have you considered Frida? What have you tried at all so far?

Comment: Thank you:) I don't quite understand how Frida can help. I am using x32dbg to label each function and variable of the application, I have extensive knowledge of it's inner workings  except for the rendering part, which is because Direct3D uses vtables. I have run apitrace with some success, but I want to find the addresses of the calls aswell, so that I can label them (manually).

Comment: I Recommand using this tool http://www.rohitab.com/gallery/api-monitor-2-0/main-window.png works for d3d9.dll and other DLL's you will see all the calls and what information is called inside the CALL's too.

Comment: If you want to see the Call Address of each function in d3d9.dll when it's called there is a tool for that too its also a API Monitor but a better more scientific check this out: https://d3.alternativeto.net/dist/s/82683d56-4dbb-e211-ab32-0025902c7e73_2_full.jpg?format=jpg&width=1200&height=1200&rmode=min (WinAPIOverride), it has call address and return address and more.

Comment: Thanks a lot :)